# Code running when it shouldn't?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I am working on a project that is mainly a photo viewer for  a photographer. The site starts with a very short video which fades out and the content fades in. The various sections of the website are accessed through a menu which triggers an ajax function that loads just that part of the page. The problem I am getting is that the video, which is only supposed to play once at the beginning, gets randomly triggered when clicking on the menu links. I don't understand this as the video has been faded out and hidden using javascript and jquery.

Here is the website (under construction):

http://maxruiz-portraits.com

```js
var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 24) + 1;
document.getElementById("front").src = "Images/PORTRAITS/Image" + random + ".jpg";

$("#content").hide();
$('#header').hide();

$(document).ready(function() {
  counter = random;
  // displayArrows();
  updateInfo(counter);

  var vid = document.getElementById("bgvid");

  function stopVideo() {
    vid.pause();
    $('#presentacion').delay(3000).hide();
    $("#bgvid").parent().hide()
    $("#bgvid").addClass('notVisible');
    $('#allIntro').hide();
  }

  setTimeout(stopVideo, 6000);

  function showSite() {
    $('#header').delay(1500).fadeIn(2000);
    $("#content").delay(1500).fadeIn(2000);
  }

  showSite();

  $('body,html').dblclick(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  });

  $(document).on('click', 'nav a', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var url = this.href;
    $("nav a.current").removeClass("current");
    $(this).addClass("current");
    $('#container').remove();
    $('#content').load(url + ' #content', function() {
      if (url == 'http://maxruiz-portraits.com/contact11.html') {
        $('title').text('Portraits | Contact');
      } else if (url == 'http://maxruiz-portraits.com/gallery2.html') {
        $('title').text('Portraits | Gallery');
      } else if (url == 'http://maxruiz-portraits.com/about.html') {
        $('title').text('Portraits | About');
        $('#english').hide();
      } else if (url == 'http://maxruiz-portraits.com/bio.html') {
        $('title').text('Portraits | Bio');
      } else if (url == 'http://maxruiz-portraits.com/home.html') {
        $('title').text('Max Ruiz | Portraits');
      }
    }).hide().fadeIn('slow');
  });

  counter = random;

  document.addEventListener('touchstart', handleTouchStart, false);
  document.addEventListener('touchmove', handleTouchMove, false);
  var xDown = null;
  var yDown = null;

  function handleTouchStart(evt) {
    xDown = evt.touches[0].clientX;
    yDown = evt.touches[0].clientY;
  };

  function handleTouchMove(evt) {
    if (!xDown || !yDown) {
      return;
    }

    var xUp = evt.touches[0].clientX;
    var yUp = evt.touches[0].clientY;

    var xDiff = xDown - xUp;
    var yDiff = yDown - yUp;
    if (Math.abs(xDiff) + Math.abs(yDiff) > 150) { //to deal with to short swipes
      if (Math.abs(xDiff) > Math.abs(yDiff)) { /*most significant*/
        if (xDiff > 0) { /* left swipe */
          counter++;
          if (counter > 24) {
            counter = 1
          }

          $('#front').fadeOut(500, function() {
            getImage(function() {
              $('#front').fadeIn(500);
            });
          });
        } else { /* right swipe */
          counter--;
          if (counter < 1) {
            counter = 24
          }

          $('#front').fadeOut(500, function() {
            getImage(function() {
              $('#front').fadeIn(500);
            });
          });
        }
      } else {
        if (yDiff > 0) { /* up swipe */
          // window.location.href = '04MaxSitePortraits/index.html';
        } else { /* down swipe */
        }
      }
      /* reset values */
      xDown = null;
      yDown = null;
    }
  };

  $(document).on('click', '.buttons', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = e.target.id;
    if (id == "next") {
      counter++;
    } else if (id == "previous") {
      counter--;
    }
    if (counter < 1) {
      counter = 24;
    } else if (counter > 24) {
      counter = 1
    }

    $('#front').fadeOut(500, function() {
      getImage(function() {
        $('#front').fadeIn(500);
      });
    });

    updateInfo(counter);
  });

  getImage = function(cb) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function() {
      document.getElementById("front").src = img.src;
      cb();
    };
    img.src = "Images/PORTRAITS/Image" + counter + ".jpg";

    // displayArrows();
  }

  // function displayArrows() {
  //    if (counter == 1) {
  //        $( '#previous' ).css('display', 'none');
  //    }
  //    else if (counter > 1 && counter < 31) {
  //        $( '#previous' ).css('display', 'block');
  //        $( '#next' ).css('display', 'block');
  //    }
  //    else if (counter == 31) {
  //      $( '#next' ).css('display', 'none');
  //    }
  // }

  $(document).on('click', '.littleImages', function(e) {
    $('#gall').removeClass("current");
    $('#home').addClass("current");

    var imageSource = $(this).attr('src');
    // find the not square picture from the square source
    var n = imageSource.lastIndexOf('/');
    var result = imageSource.substring(n + 1);
    var imageSourceFinal = 'Images/PORTRAITS/' + result;

    // find the counter in order to know if it's the last or the first picture and hide corr arrow

    counter = imageSource.match(/\d+/g);
    $('#container').remove();
    $('#content').load('index.html' + ' #content', function() {
      $('#front').attr('src', imageSourceFinal);

      // if (counter == 1) { $( '#previous' ).css('display', 'none');}
      // if (counter == 31){ $( '#next' ).css('display', 'none');}

      // updateInfo(counter);
      testFunction(counter[0]);
    }).hide().fadeIn('slow');
  });

  if (/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
    $("#front").on("mousedown", function() {
      updateInfo(counter);
      $('#front').fadeTo(300, 0.3);
      $('#info').fadeTo(300, 1);
      setTimeout(infoMobileOut, 1000);
    });
  } else {
    $(document).on('mouseover', '#front', function() {
      $('#front').fadeTo(300, 0.3);
      $('#info').fadeTo(300, 1);
    });

    $(document).on('mouseout', '#front', function() {
      $('#front').fadeTo(300, 1);
      $('#info').fadeTo(300, 0);
    });
  }

  function infoMobileOut() {
    $('#front').fadeTo(300, 1);
    $('#info').fadeTo(300, 0);
  }

  function testFunction(number) {
    switch (number) {
      case "1":
        $('#info').text('Photo 1');
        break;
      case "2":
        $('#info').text('Photo 2');
        break;
      case "3":
        $('#info').text('Photo 3');
        break;
      case "4":
        $('#info').text('Photo 4');
        break;
      case "5":
        $('#info').text('Photo 5');
        break;
      case "6":
        $('#info').text('Photo 6');
        break;
      case "7":
        $('#info').text('Photo 7');
        break;
      case "8":
        $('#info').text('Photo 8');
        break;
      case "9":
        $('#info').text('Photo 9');
        break;
      case "10":
        $('#info').text('Photo 10');
        break;
      case "11":
        $('#info').text('Photo 11');
        break;
      case "12":
        $('#info').text('Photo 12');
        break;
      case "13":
        $('#info').text('Photo 13');
        break;
      case "14":
        $('#info').text('Photo 14');
        break;
      case "15":
        $('#info').text('Photo 15');
        break;
      case "16":
        $('#info').text('Photo 16');
        break;
      case "17":
        $('#info').text('Photo 17');
        break;
      case "18":
        $('#info').text('Photo 18');
        break;
      case "19":
        $('#info').text('Photo 19');
        break;
      case "20":
        $('#info').text('Photo 20');
        break;
      case "21":
        $('#info').text('Photo 21');
        break;
      case "22":
        $('#info').text('Photo 22');
        break;
      case "23":
        $('#info').text('Photo 23');
        break;
      case "24":
        $('#info').text('Photo 24');
        break;
    }
  }

  function updateInfo(number) {
    switch (number) {
      case 1:
        $('#info').text('Photo 1');
        break;
      case 2:
        $('#info').text('Photo 2');
        break;
      case 3:
        $('#info').text('Photo 3');
        break;
      case 4:
        $('#info').text('Photo 4');
        break;
      case 5:
        $('#info').text('Photo 5');
        break;
      case 6:
        $('#info').text('Photo 6');
        break;
      case 7:
        $('#info').text('Photo 7');
        break;
      case 8:
        $('#info').text('Photo 8');
        break;
      case 9:
        $('#info').text('Photo 9');
        break;
      case 10:
        $('#info').text('Photo 10');
        break;
      case 11:
        $('#info').text('Photo 11');
        break;
      case 12:
        $('#info').text('Photo 12');
        break;
      case 13:
        $('#info').text('Photo 13');
        break;
      case 14:
        $('#info').text('Photo 14');
        break;
      case 15:
        $('#info').text('Photo 15');
        break;
      case 16:
        $('#info').text('Photo 16');
        break;
      case 17:
        $('#info').text('Photo 17');
        break;
      case 18:
        $('#info').text('Photo 18');
        break;
      case 19:
        $('#info').text('Photo 19');
        break;
      case 20:
        $('#info').text('Photo 20');
        break;
      case 21:
        $('#info').text('Photo 21');
        break;
      case 22:
        $('#info').text('Photo 22');
        break;
      case 23:
        $('#info').text('Photo 23');
        break;
      case 24:
        $('#info').text('Photo 24');
        break;
    }
  }

  $(document).on('click', '#enButton', function() {
    $('#english').fadeIn();
    $('#french').fadeOut();
  });

  $(document).on('click', '#frButton', function() {
    $('#english').fadeOut();
    $('#french').fadeIn();
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <a href="index.html">
    <title>Max Ruiz | Portraits</title>
  </a>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (max-device-width: 480px)" href="mobile_style.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px)" href="mobilePad_style.css" />
</head>
<body>
  <div id="allIntro">
    <div>
      <video playsinline autoplay loop id="bgvid" class="visible">
          <source src="Images/PORTRAITS/introportraits.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
    </div>
    <div id="presentacion">
      <h1>PORTRAITS</h1>
      <h2>PHOTOGRAPHIES </br id="break">DE MAX RUIZ</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="header">
    <div id="title">
      <h1>MAX RUIZ <span id="parana">PORTRAITS</span></h1>
    </div>
    <div id="infoMob">
      <a href="info.html"><img src="Images/infoMob.png" /></a>
    </div>
    <nav class="cf" id="menu">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="contact11.html">CONTACT</a></li>
        <li><a href="bio.html">BIO</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html">ABOUT</a></li>
        <li><a href="gallery2.html" id="gall">GALLERY</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.html" id="home" class="current">HOME</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <section id="content">
    <div id="container">
      <div id="imagewrap">
        <img src="Images/PORTRAITS/Image1.jpg" id="front" class="bigImage" />
        <div id="info">Verde</div>
        <div id="previous" class="buttons"></div>
        <div id="next" class="buttons"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="JavaScript5.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Any ideas as to why the video is reloaded when clicking on the menu links? Thank you.

Comment: Just FYI your two massive `switch` statements can be replaced entirely by `$('#info').text('Photo ' + number);`

Comment: The website you linked contains nudity. Can you please remove it and try to bring your code down to a [mcve]?

Comment: it works for me on firefox, no randomly triggered videos here...

Comment: Hi, thanks for both comments. I am sorry about the nudity, I overlooked that. I will remove the picture immediately.

Comment: works well with Fire fox..

Comment: For me the video replays every time I click any menu link, and this happens in safari, firefox and chrome

Comment: Rory the names of the pictures need to be added, it won't be "photo 1", "photo 2" when the site is finished, it will be the names of the models. But I like your comment, it shows you think in code terms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Problem is, that you disable your video after 6 seconds, but your content is visible after 3,5 seconds. Your site will actually work after 6 seconds, but if you try to click a link before 6 seconds, you will see the video once more, since you cleared the content that was above the video and fading in new content. Try to change this line:

```
setTimeout(stopVideo, 6000);
```

to maybe

```
setTimeout(stopVideo, 3500);
```

maybe you need further changes, but I think you got the idea of what is going wrong

Comment: actually you have a serious performance problem on your page, every time you click home and try to load `index.html` browser will go nuts and raise CPU usage, so after you clicked 10 times on home the browser requires 100 % cpu time until you close your site. I think its because you load the entire index.html once more and probably triggers timers and stuff. Try to create a javascript-less .html for your home-page and check if the problem still exists

Comment: or maybe the problem is that the browser try to play the video, even when you only requests `#content`... either way try to create a new `home.html` with only `#content` element and use it to render the `home` page